# NVENC : fail to compress H264 with for multiple video streams

Tags: gpu, video-encoding

I have two Quadro K620 NVidia video cards.  I want to compress 4 H.264 streams using NVENC SDK, 2 streams per card. video is 640x 480 30 fps.

2 streams working well without any problem but It's failed when I try to encod 3 Streams.

The function nvEncOpenEncodeSessionEx return NV_ENC_ERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY error in 3th stream.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, NVENC has nothing to do with CUDA, so you are unlikely to find help by tagging the question with this tag. From the error message it would appear that you have hit a limit of NVENC on the number of concurrent streams. Double check the NVENC documentation for any limits on the number of streams supported (either hard limit, or based on capability of particular GPUs).

Comment: Quadro  K620 support 2 streaming. I plug in two K620 cards in my PC. And I use second video card for 3th Stream. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I found it. NVENC documentation says "The current SDK package allows up to two simultaneous encode sessions per system for low-end Quadro and GeForce cards."  But I'm not sure what is " low-end" for.Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Quadro K620 is definitely low-end.If you look at NVIDIA's Quadro overview (http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-desktop-gpus.html), whis is sorted high-end to low-end, the K620 appears at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me what is minimum board so that I can compress 4 streams?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I would suggest contacting NVIDIA tech support.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs due to a [licensing limitations](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/NVENC_DA-06209-001_v07.pdf?autho=1452972945_d6791efa67031b38127384c5c437f683&file=NVENC_DA-06209-001_v07.pdf) 
 Please read this: "Following  is  the  difference  between  licensing  policies  staring R358  driver(s) and  the  previous driver(s) . In  driver(s) earlier to R358 , two  simultaneous encoding sessions per  system  were  allowed  irrespective  of  the  number  of  non - qualified  GPUs  present  in  the  system.  For example,  on  systems with  one  Quadro K4000  card  and  two  GeForce  cards,  only  two  simultaneous  encode  sessions  could  be  ru n,  regardless  of  which  GPU  is  running the encode session. Starting  R358 , the restriction of two simultaneous encoding  sessions  will  apply  only to  the  combined number  of  sessions  executed  on  all  non - qualified  cards . In the example above, the application can run  N simultaneous encode sessions on  Quadro  K4000  card  (where  N is  defined  by  the encoder/memory/hardware  limitations)  and  two  sessions  on  both  GeForce  cards  combined.  Thus  the  limit  on  the  number  of  simultaneous encode sessions for such a system is  N +  2"
A minimum board supports more than 2 NVENC threads in parallel is a **QUADRO K2000** 
 Please see [NVENC SUPPOTED GPUs](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk)

Comment: Do you know if you can overcome this issue by running a virtualizer (kvm) and assigning one card to each vm?  Say you have 2 cards and create 2 vm... would I be able to run 4 sessions? Or is the control done at the hardware level?

Comment: @NublaII It's a good idea, but, I'm not checked it. The control done at the driver level. I think this answer will be useful for you:
http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17419/what-graphics-card-features-effect-nvidia-nvenc-hardware-encoding-speed/17943#17943

Comment: I can confirm that using kvm and passthrough for the cards I can encode 4 streams simultaneously ;)